# Ubuntu not showing up in boot menu after first installation

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, uefi

I just installed Ubuntu using a USB. Everything was fine and it installed and said that the computer needed to restart. After restarting, it booted straight to Windows. I tried opening the boot menu by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd>, and the only available option was to boot in Windows.

Picture of my boot priority order:

[image: Picture of my boot priority order]

I have tried disabling SecureBoot and it's still not working. The version I installed was a 64-bit version of Ubuntu 20.04.1.

Answer (score 0):

1. Disable SecureBoot.
2. Change boot mode to Legacy/CSM from UEFI.
3. Change Boot order so that your HDD (i.e. Toshiba in your case) becomes the first one.  Try these options and revert if not successful.

Regards.

Comment: I’ve done this. Now when I open the boot menu, it gives three options: 1.) HDD : TOSHIBA MQ01ABD100 2.) ATAPI CDROM : HL -DT -ST DVDRAM GUE1N 3.) Network Boot : RealTek PXE B01 D00

Comment: after editing these options and **"saving before your exit"**, what are the options presented to you at reboot of your system?  Is it again windows gets loaded after selecting HDD??

Comment: Yes, it reboots straight to Windows

Comment: Please share an image of your windows boot loader

Comment: https://imgur.com/gallery/HfGXCuG

Comment: https://imgur.com/gallery/8sNxHzW this is the screen I get after selecting HDD

Comment: After selecting option 1: HDD it boots into windows, right?  If yes, your bootloader installation of ubuntu did not went through well.  Seems an installation issue regarding selection of options while installing.  Try re-installing ubuntu using live USB and remember to install boot configuration in /dev/sda and if asks to replace bootloader, select yes.